# Use of ref to prevent often-changing value from useCallback

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, ref

In the Reach Hooks FAQ section ["How to read an often-changing value from useCallback?"](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-read-an-often-changing-value-from-usecallback) there is an example:

```
function Form() {
  const [text, updateText] = useState('');
  const textRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    textRef.current = text; // Write it to the ref
  });

  const handleSubmit = useCallback(() => {
    const currentText = textRef.current; // Read it from the ref
    alert(currentText);
  }, [textRef]); // Don't recreate handleSubmit like [text] would do

  return (
    <>
      <input value={text} onChange={e => updateText(e.target.value)} />
      <ExpensiveTree onSubmit={handleSubmit} />
    </>
  );
}
```

I was so confused:

- Instead of useCallback updating the function each time the text changes, this code moves it to textRef in useEffect.  But isn't that the same because the callback function doesn't change but you still need 1 step to update the value in useEffect?
- Why is textRef in the dependency array?  Isn't textRef a reference which doesn't change between renders?  We always receive the same reference so wouldn't it be the same as inputting an empty array?

Answer (score 0):

> instead of useCallback update the function each time the text change, this code move it to textRef in useEffect but isn't that the same because the callback function doesn't change but you still need 1 step to update the value in useEffect?

With the `useRef` setup, each render re-runs `useEffect` but `handleSubmit` stays the same.  In a normal setup, each render would re-run `useCallback` and `handleSubmit` would be a new reference to a new function.  I can see why on the surface this seems like the same amount of work.

The benefits of the ref approach are what **other** re-renders happen based on a re-rendering of `Form`.  Each time the value of `text` changes, the parent `Form` re-renders and the child `input` re-renders since it takes `text` as a prop.  **`ExpensiveTree` does not re-render** because its prop `handleSubmit` maintains the same reference.  Of course the name `ExpensiveTree` is designed to tell us that we want to minimize re-rendering of that component since it is computationally expensive.